# Matching a String to a Generated RDF Entity in Python

Tags: python, string, rdf, matching

I'm trying to match Subject and Object strings to an RDF that contains them, however the strings are altered and so its tough to generate an exact match. I'm trying to just match the most similar, but difflib doesn't seem to work. So I have:

```
subject = "Juliette Gruber"
```

and an .rdf that looks something like this (shortened for this post):

```
    <j.3:hasDeterminer rdf:resource="http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/fred/quantifiers.owl#a"/>

    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/fred/domain.owl#Actor"/>

  </rdf:Description>

  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/fred/domain.owl#Actor">

    <owl:equivalentClass rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Actor"/>

  </rdf:Description>

  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/fred/domain.owl#ProbablyBestKnow">

    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/fred/domain.owl#BestKnow"/>

  </rdf:Description>

  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/fred/domain.owl#Juliette_gruber">

    <owl:sameAs rdf:resource="http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/fred/domain.owl#actor_1"/>

    <j.1:hasQuality rdf:resource="http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/fred/domain.owl#British"/>

    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/fred/domain.owl#BritishActor"/>

  </rdf:Description>
```

**I'm trying to use the subject variable to find the line that contains it**, but I can't seem to figure out a reliable method for doing so. This is just an example, I'm trying to do this with many subjects/objects/RDFs. I've tried using difflib and grabbing just one word from the subject/object, but this is inconsistent and often does not work.

Comment: I do not understand the question. What exactly isyour goal? What is input, what is output?

Comment: I have a large list of sentences. Two things have been done to them: 1) an entity has been extracted ("Juliette Gruber", above), and 2) the sentence has been parsed into an RDF graph, like the one above. Now, I am trying to find the RDF graph entry that contains "Juliette Gruber", however I'm not sure how to match: `Juliette Gruber` with `http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/fred/domain.owl#Juliette_gruber`. Also, this is just an example, I'm trying to find a solution that will work for many versions of this problem

Comment: 1.) If you're using Python you should use rdflib API 2) if your create the RDF data for a sentence, you should add `rdfs:label` data to the entities with the string - this is best practice and allows for retrieving the data by looking at the labels. For example, then you could use SPARQL ,e.g. `select * where {?s rdfs:label "Juliette Gruber"}`

Comment: I'm not generating the RDF though, a closed-source API is

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly then using pattern matching we can get the required string and generate the require uri and you can match it with the desired object . Even if the triples are repeated the knowledge graph would recognize them as the same

Comment: Correct, perhaps a regex to search the several URIs for any iteration of the ```subject``` string